# Figuring out coefficients of composition of a first degree polynomial into a quadratic

Tags: quadratics

> given $g(x)=x^2 + x-2$ and $ g \circ f = 2 [2x^2-5x +2]$, find $f(x)$ ( $f(x)$ is form $ax+b$)

I found the inverse of g as two functions,

$$ y =( x + \frac12)^2  - \frac94 $$

$$  \pm (\sqrt{y + \frac94} -\frac12 ) = x$$

or,

$ g^{-1} (y) =   \pm (\sqrt{y + \frac94} -\frac12 ) $

Ok, so  into this function I plugged in $ y=  g \circ f = 2 [2x^2 - 5x +2]$

and this gave me:

$ f(x) = \begin{cases} 2x -3 \\
                   2-2x \\
               \end{cases}$

Now there are two different functions which f(x) could have been.

Now, If I try do this another way, that is, using derivatives,

$$ g( ax+b) = (ax+b)^2 + (ax+b) -2$$

$$ g \circ f = 2 [ 2x^2 - 5x +2]$$

Equating the two different definitions,

$$ 2 [ 2x^2 - 5x +2]=(ax+b)^2 + (ax+b) -2$$

Taking a derivative,

$$ 2 ( ax+b)a + a- 2 = 8x - 10$$

And one more,

$$ 2 a^2 = 8 $$

$$ a^2= 4$$

Evaluating the equation after first derivative at x=0, I get $ b=-6$

so, $ f(x) = 4x - 6$

which is inconsistent with the previous answer. What went wrong?

Edit: fixed a method in derivative.

Comment: Your derivative is incorrect. The derivative of $(ax+b)^2$ is $2a(ax+b)$.

Comment: Ahhh facepalm thank you for noting that

Comment: Little remark : "coefficient", not "co-efficient" (which would mean - maybe - a group of people who do efficient work when working together)

Comment: Haha Jean :D, I'll have that fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more easy way is the following :

If $f(x)=ax+b$, then
$$g \circ f(x) = (ax+b)^2 + (ax+b) - 2 = a^2x^2 + (2ab+a)x + (b^2+b-2)$$

By identification, you must have $a^2 = 4$, $2ab+a = -10$ and $b^2+b-2 = 4$. If $a=2$, you obtain $b=-3$ which works ; if $a=-2$, you obtain $b=2$ which also works. So you have two solutions :
$$f(x) = 2x-3 \quad \text{ and } \quad f(x)=-2x+2 $$

Comment: Very nice, I have one question though how do I interpret the two inverses? like I got a plus or minus on the inverse, what are your thoughts on it?

Comment: Actually $g^{-1} (y) =   \pm (\sqrt{y + \frac94} -\frac12 )$ has no sense. The function $g$ is not bijective, so you are not allowed to talk about $g^{-1}$.

Comment: I see, then how exactly did the solution I did using inverse method work? I don't think it was just luck that I got the solution.

Comment: The writing is incorrect. A correct way to write your idea would be to say : we are looking $f$ such that $f(x)^2 + f(x) - 2 = 4x^2-10x + 4$. And now you can solve the quadratic equation, and find the two solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Your  "completing the square" could also be used this way.  We have $$ \ g(x) \ = \ x^2 + x - 2 \ = \ (x+2)·(x-1) \ = \ \left( x + \frac12 \right)^2  - \frac94 \ \ $$ and
$$ \ [g \circ f](x) \ = \ 2·(2x^2 - 5x + 2) \ = \ 2·(2x-1)·(x-2) \ = \ 4· \left( x - \frac54 \right)^2  - \frac94 \ \ .  $$
The zeroes of these polynomials are then $ \ -\frac12 \pm \frac32 \ = \ -2 \ , \ 1 \ \ $ and $ \ \frac54 \pm \frac{3}{2·\sqrt4} \ = \ \frac12 \ , \ 2 \ \ . $

The composition   $ \ [g \circ f](x) \ = \ g(ax+b) \ \ $ corresponds to curve transformations of a "horizontal stretch" and "horizontal shift" for $ \ a > 0 \ $ and includes a "horizontal reflection" about the $ \ y-$axis for $ \ a < 0 \ \ . $  There is no effect on $ \ y-$coordinates of points.

The vertex of the parabola for $ \ g(x) \ $ is then located at $ \ \left(-\frac12 \ , \ -\frac94 \right) \ \ $ and is to be transformed to the vertex $ \ \left( \frac54 \ , \ -\frac94 \right) \ \ .  $ There are two possibilities for the transformation of the zeroes:

•  for $ \ a > 0 \ \ , $ the "stretch and shift" is itself a composition $ \ a·\left(x + \frac{b}{a} \right) \ ; $

•  for $ \ a < 0 \ \ , $ the added "reflection" makes this $ \ -|a|·\left(x - \frac{b}{|a|} \right) \ . $

The transformations are thus
$$ \left( \ [ax+b] \ + \ \frac12 \ \right)^2 \ \ = \ \ a^2·\left( \  x \ + \ \frac{b}{a} \ + \ \frac{1}{2·a} \ \right)^2 \ \ = \ \ 4· \left( x - \frac54 \right)^2   $$
$$ \Rightarrow \ \ a^2 \ = \ 4 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ a \ = \ \pm 2 \ \ , $$
for which we have either
$$ a \  =  \ +2 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \  \frac{b}{2} \ + \  \frac{1}{2·2} \ \ = \ \ - \frac54  \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ b \ = \ -3 \ \  $$
or
$$ a \  =  \ -2 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \  \frac{b}{-2} \ + \  \frac{1}{2·[-2]} \ \ = \ \ - \frac54  \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ b \ = \ +2 \ \ . $$

We can check on how the zeroes are transformed to verify these results:

$$ \mathbf{g( 2x - 3 ) = 0 \ : } \quad   2x - 3 \ = \ -2 \ \ \rightarrow \ \ x \ = \ \frac{-2}{2} \ + \ \frac32 \ = \  \frac12 \ \ \ , $$ $$ 2x - 3 \ = \ 1 \ \ \rightarrow \ \ x \ = \ \frac12 \ + \ \frac32 \ = \ 2  \ \ , $$
so points on the parabola are effectively "compressed" toward the symmetry axis, and said axis translates "to the right";

$$ \mathbf{g( -2x + 2 ) = 0 \ : } \quad   -2x + 2 \ = \ -2 \ \ \rightarrow \ \ x \ = \ \frac{-2}{-2} \ + \ \frac{2}{-2} \ = \  2 \ \ \ , $$ $$ -2x + 2 \ = \ 1 \ \ \rightarrow \ \ x \ = \frac{1}{-2} \ + \ \frac{2}{-2} \ = \  \frac12  \ \ , $$
so  points are  "compressed" toward the symmetry axis, reflected around it, and effectively the  axis  translates "to the right".